# How to delete object in Realm properly and thread-safe

Tags: ios, multithreading, object, exception, realm

I've just starting to using Realm and feel it's very good, fast except one thing: delete an object in Realm is easily cause an exception.

Is there any way I can delete an object in Realm safety?

In my project, I usually have to create, update, delete hundred objects on the background thread. The issue is:

- If the app currently display/using one object on the main thread
- In the background, I delete that object. 
  => On the main thread will cause an exception when using that object's properties.

I know Realm has isInvalid method to check, but I cannot add the check in every assign properties code, it's look not good.

So, as of now, what I do is: instead of actually delete, I have a property call "deleted", and in delete, I only update that value. And on the UI, I will filtered out objects which have deleted = true

I wonder is there any way better to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended functionality. If a background thread deletes a Realm `Object`, the next time you try and access that object from any thread, an exception will be thrown.

In order to handle this, Realm provides [a rich notification system](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) that you can use to automatically receive alerts of when the contents of a Realm database have been changed and to update the UI accordingly.

If you've got a view controller that is displaying the contents of a single Realm `Object`, you could implement a system to be notified of any changes being made to your Realm database, and then check to make sure your object is still valid:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
   var myModel: Object = nil
   var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

   init(model: Object) {
      self.myModel = model
   }

   override fun viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      notificationToken = myModel.realm.addNotificationBlock { notification, realm in
         guard myModel.invalidated == false else {
            // The object has been deleted, so dismiss this view controller
         }
      }
   }

   deinit() {
      notificationToken?.stop()
   }
}
```

That notification block will be triggered each time a write transaction modified something in that particular Realm file (Even on background threads), which gives you a chance to check to see if your particular Realm `Object` in that UI hasn't been deleted. If it has, then you can simply dismiss the UI.

Depending on your specific needs, there is also a more fine-grained notification system you can use to specifically track changes to Realm `Objects` that were part of the results of a query. There's sample code for that in the [Collection Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications) of the Realm documentation.

Please let me know if you need additional clarification! :)

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will try your solution (y)

Comment: Thanks Quan! If that took care of everything you were asking, please mark the answer as accepted. ;)